# How to reshape data in SQL Server when there are multiple elements in a single group and each element has unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my dataset there are primary account holders and individuals joint to that account, each individual has their own account information number aswell as a sales number.

```
select distinct 
    cust.no_ as 'CUST1 number', 
    cust.sales as 'CUST1 sales',
    cust2.no_ as 'CUST2 number', 
    cust2.sales as 'CUST2 sales'
from 
    cust
left join 
    dmd on dmd.rowno_custdmd_cust = cust.rowno
left join
    dmdjnt on dmdjnt.rowno_dmdjnt_dmd = dmd.rowno
left join
    cust as cust2 on cust2.rowno = dmdjnt.rowno_dmdjnt_cust2
```

Output:

```
CUST1 Number    CUST1 Sales Number  CUST2 Number    CUST2 Sales Number
1               111                 2               22
1               111                 3               333
1               111                 4               44
1               111                 5               55555
6               666                 NULL            NULL
7               777                 8               88
```

I have tried the following, this lists all the numbers but because the sales number may not be the highest it does not work

```
select distinct 
    cust.no_ as 'CUST1 number',
    min(cust2.no_) as 'CUST2 number', 
    (case 
        when min(cust2.no_) <> max(cust2.no_) 
           then max(cust2.no_) 
     end) as 'CUST3 number'
from 
    cust
left join
    dmd on dmd.rowno_custdmd_cust = cust.rowno
left join
    dmdjnt on dmdjnt.rowno_dmdjnt_dmd = dmd.rowno
left join
    cust as cust2 on cust2.rowno = dmdjnt.rowno_dmdjnt_cust2
```

I would the results to look like this:

```
CUST1 Number    CUST1 Sales Number  CUST2 Number    CUST2 Sales Number  CUST3 Number    CUST3 Sales Number  CUST4 Number    CUST4 Sales Number  CUST5 Number    CUST5 Sales Number
1   111 2   22  3   333 4   44  5   55555
6   666 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
7   777 8   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```